# remove default search box and add custom one in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jquery datatable. My required is to remove default search box and add custom one in difference place. I use `bFilter:false` for remove the search input but it is also disabling search filter functionality. Any Idea how to fix it without using css [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yg32o2yh/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   var table= $('#example').DataTable({
        paging:false,
        bFilter:false,
        ordering:false
    });

    $('#search-inp').keyup(function(){
      table.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})

});
```

Comment: Just remove the `<input type="text" id="search-inp">` and keep the `id` to set it to your custom input, you can also place it wherever you need (I managed to place the search text at bottom, so technically you can do whatever you want).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `dom` option to hide the search input without disabling the search functionality. This is useful if you want to provide your own inputs for searching (perhaps on a column by column basis, or globally). It also accomplishes what you asked for initially - remove the original search input without using CSS.

Here is the documentation: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

And, of course, an example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        bFilter: false,
        ordering: false,
        searching: true,
        dom: 't'         // This shows just the table
    });
```

You could also use this method to render the search input in a different place. Depending on where you need to render the input, you may be able to avoid using a custom one altogether.

Answer (score 30):

For Hiding Default Search Input box of Data tables AS: 
by default **sDom="lftipr";**

> Perform these operations on datatables 
>       'l' - Length changing
>       'f' - Filtering input
>       't' - The table!
>       'i' - Information
>       'p' - Pagination
>       'r' - pRocessing
>   For removing default search box just remove the f character from sDom.

**like**:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
  "sDom":"ltipr"
});
```

Hope this must work

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for this!

Comment: This uses the [legacy API](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom) and is a suitable answer if you can't upgrade to the current version of DataTables.

Comment: let  oTable = $('#tableName').DataTable({
                "sDom": "ltipr",
                "searching": true)};
there are other options to hide that box searching: false but that also stops custom filtration on client side. So this is the most logical answer as custom searching/filtration is still working.

Answer (score 7):

`bFilter` actually removes the search functionality so what I suggest it just hide the default search and then you can implement your custom search with the code you have already written. Just check below code:

```
#example_filter //#example is your table id, so you can replace it with whatever Id you give to table
{
    display:none;
}
```

**Note :** Remove `bFilter` during initialization

Then your normal coding. Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yg32o2yh/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

As Guruprasad mentioned, 'bfilter': false removes the search functionality. So you need to use the 'dom' option.

Also dom comes with markup and styling functionalities. So if you need the exact datatable styling then you should use

> $('#example').dataTable( {dom:
>   '<"row"lr><"row"<"col-xs-12"t>><"row"<"col-sm-6"i><"col-sm-6"p>>'});

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your css
.dataTables_filter { display: none;}

it will hide default search box and you can use your own search box, there is no need for bfilter : false